# PHP Reading plain text with newline?

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents, plaintext

I have a plain text file (text.txt):

```
11. Bonus: In humans, it is composed of 24 vertebrae plus the sacrum and coccyx. For ten points each:
[10] Identify this support structure found in almost all chordates. An excessive curvature of this structure results in scoliosis, and it usually takes a slim "S" shape in an upright human.
ANSWER: spine (or spinal column; accept backbone; accept vertebral column)
[10] The embryos of many chordates contain this precursor to the spinal column, which is essentially a flexible support rod made of collagen. Unlike most other chordates, lancelets retain this structure as adults.
ANSWER: notochord
[10] These members of the subphylum Urochordata possess notochords as larvae, but then promptly lose it and settle down as sessile filter feeders devoid of any vertebrate characteristics.
ANSWER: tunicates (or sea squirts)

12. Bonus: This novel's protagonist is chased by Detective Fix, who thinks he is a bank robber. For ten points each:
[10] Identify this Jules Verne novel in which Phileas Fogg bets that he can circumnavigate the globe in a certain amount of time.
ANSWER: Around the World in Eighty Days (or Le tour de monde en quatre-vingts jours)
[10] In this Verne novel, Professor Lindenbrock finds a coded note in a Snorri Sturulson book, prompting an adventure through the subterranean world before escaping during an eruption of Stromboli.
ANSWER: Journey to the Center of the Earth (or Voyage au centre de la Terre)
[10] This novel is a sequel to both In Search of the Castaways and Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea. In it, Cyrus Smith and other Union soldiers escape from Richmond on a hot-air balloon, but get stuck in the title locale.
ANSWER: The Mysterious Island (or L'Île mystérieuse)

13. Bonus: He owns the spear Gungnir and sacrificed an eye to drink from the Well of Mimir. For ten points each:
[10] Name this owner of the ravens Hugin and Munin who was the chief Norse deity and father of the Aesir.
ANSWER: Odin (accept Wotan or Woden)
[10] With his brothers Vili and Ve, Odin killed this primordial giant to build the world. He was formed in Ginnungagap by the union of fire and ice.
ANSWER: Ymir (accept Augelmir or close pronunciations of that)
[10] This cold and icy realm met with the fiery Muspelheim to create Ymir. According to some sources, the wicked dead are sent to this place instead of Hel.
ANSWER: Niflheimr
```

In my PHP script I am trying to read this file so I can parse it later, but when I read the file, the newlines do not appear and the whole thing looks like one long line.

Here is my PHP:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
$text = file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo $text;
```

It it makes any difference, I am using Textedit on the mac to create the plain text file.

Comment: i bet a million bucks the new lines are there, how every if you expect a browser, which expects html to add a line break ...

Comment: @Dagon even in the 'view source' windows, it is all still one line.

Comment: dam it, how would you like payment?

Comment: What happens if you use php function nl2br?

Comment: just because you can't see them in the source windows doesn't mean they're not there. also why not check if the string contains a `\n`? this is very easy to do in php with functions like `strpos` or `strstr`. then you'll know for sure.

Comment: @sgroves if I copy and paste the contents of the plain text file into the actual php document and save it as a variable and then echo that variable, the newlines show in the source window, but they down if I use the process above.

Comment: try creating a new file in another editor that you're SURE will have the newlines, then try loading that with php. then you'll know 100% sure whether it's textedit or not. i don't see why it would be textedit though—if you re-open a file you saved with textedit and can still see multiple lines, then obviously newline characters of some sort are there. perhaps textedit saves them as `\r\n` and `file_get_contents` doesn't understand that (this also seems unlikely ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the newline in text file is stored as '\n' and so HTML would not recognize it.
For this, you have to replace all `\n` with `<br />` so that they are echoed properly.

Example:

```
$text=str_replace("\n","<br />",$text);
```

I hope it helps..!!

EDIT:

You can also use `<pre>` tags around $text to print it as it is.

Example:

```
echo "<pre>".$text."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because PHP outputs with a HTTP content-type header set to "text/html" by default. The newlines are still there (try view source)

Comment: It is all still one line even in the view source.

Comment: Try adding:   header('Content-Type: text/plain');    to the top of the file

Comment: I am using Chrome. My theory is that it has something to do with newlines in Textedit on Mac.

Comment: why not look into textedit's preferences and see if there's something about linebreaks? textedit doesn't have many preferences so that shouldn't take long. if there's no option for it, then your problem probably is not textedit, as many people have used textedit to create files they read with php, and i don't see anything on google about this issue.

Comment: @sgroves I made it with a difference text editor (Sublime Text 2), and well, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to the top of your script. So it looks like:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
$text = file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo $text;
?>
```

view-source output in Chrome: http://pastie.org/8080064